# Can parameter pack function arguments be defaulted?

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, clang, variadic-templates

This is a point about which gcc 4.9.2 and clang 3.5.2 are in sharp
disagreement. The program:

```
template<typename ...Ts>
int foo(int i = 0, Ts &&... args)
{
    return i + sizeof...(Ts);
}

int main()
{
    return foo();
}
```

compiles without comment from gcc (`-std=c++11 -Wall -pedantic`). Clang says:

```
error: missing default argument on parameter 'args'
```

With `foo` amended to:

```
template<typename ...Ts>
int foo(int i = 0, Ts &&... args = 0)
{
    return i + sizeof...(Ts);
}
```

clang has no complaints, but gcc says:

```
error: parameter pack ‘args’ cannot have a default argument
```

Which compiler is right?

Comment: You could work around it by overloading: `template <typename... Ts> int foo(int i, Ts&&...) { return i + sizeof...(Ts); } inline int foo() { return foo(0); }`

Answer (score 27, accepted):

From 8.3.6 ([dcl.fct.default])/3:

> A default argument shall not be specified for a parameter pack.

From 8.3.6 ([dcl.fct.default])/4:

> In a given function declaration, each parameter subsequent to a parameter with a default argument shall have a default argument supplied in this or a previous declaration or shall be a function parameter pack.

So this allows code like `void f(int a = 10, Args ... args)`, or indeed like your first snippet. (Thanks to @T.C. for looking up the second sentence!)

Comment: [dcl.fct.default]/4 ("In a given function declaration, each parameter subsequent to a parameter with a default argument
shall have a default argument supplied in this or a previous declaration or shall be a function parameter pack.") would appear to permit the first version.

Comment: @KerrekSB Yes, so it permits the version accepted by GCC.

Comment: @T.C.: Yes, thanks, I've absorbed that into the post if you don't mind :-)

Comment: clang bugs filed: [23028](https://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=23028) [23029](https://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=23029)

Comment: Fixed in trunk, so will be fixed in the next release of clang. That was quick!

Answer (score 5):

A Kerrek SB says, it's not possible. What you could do, instead, is using a `std::tuple`

```
template <class ... Args>
void foo( std::tuple<Args...> t = std::tuple<int>(0) )
{}
```