# Are variadic arguments after a defaulted parameter well-formed?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++14, variadic-templates

```
template <typename... Args>
void bark( int = 0, Args&&... args ) {}

int main() {
     bark();
     bark(1);
     bark(1, 2);
}
```

Is this code well-formed according to the C++ Standard?

The proposed duplicate does not contain the same calls of the function.

Comment: Not a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29098835/can-parameter-pack-function-arguments-be-defaulted, doesn't contain calls of the same form.

Comment: Looks like a duplicate to me. Even if the invocation isn't identical, the answer in that question shows the two parts of the standard that say it's not valid even in this case.

Comment: The issue raised in that question has been fixed in Clang, but Clang still rejects this code.

Comment: Hmm I misread the standard snippet in the answer there. It actually _is_ supposed to be valid code according to the standard. It's still a duplicate though. Your form is identical to the first part of that question.

Comment: I am still confused on why this is not a dupe.  The other question answers this.

Comment: Like I said, the other question doesn't contain the same calls of the function.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Due to [CWG 777](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#777), the declaration is valid:

> In a given function declaration, **all each parameters subsequent to a
>   parameter with a default argument** shall have a default arguments
>   supplied in this or a previous declarations **or shall be a function
>   parameter pack**.

Deduction should succeed in all three cases, since the default argument makes no difference to the nature of deduction: If no argument to the pack parameter `args` is provided, it's deduced to the empty pack via [[temp.arg.explicit]/3](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.arg.explicit#3), otherwise the usual rule in [[temp.deduct.call]/1](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.deduct.call#1) applies (as the pack is clearly not in a non-deduced context).