# Parameter pack after default arguments

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates, c++17, default-arguments

I have the following struct with a variadic constructor with a default argument:

```
struct S {
    template<typename... Args>
    S(int n=0, Args&& ...args) {}
};

int main() {
    S s1;       // fine on clang and g++ (S(0) by default argument, empty Args)
    S s2(1);    // fine on clang and g++ (S(1), empty Args)
    S s3(1, 2); // fine on g++ (S(1, 2), non-empty Args), clang complains (see below)
}
```

As indicated, `S(1, 2)` compiles fine on `g++` (version 7.3, tested with flags `-std=c++1z` and `-std=c++14`), but `clang` (version 6.0.0, tested with the same flags) tells me the following:

```
<source>:3:26: error: missing default argument on parameter 'args'
    S(int n=0, Args&& ...args) {}
                         ^
<source>:9:7: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'S::S<int>' requested here
    S s3(1, 2); // fine on g++ (S(1, 2), non-empty Args), clang complains (see below)
      ^
```

I already found [Can parameter pack function arguments be defaulted?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29098835/can-parameter-pack-function-arguments-be-defaulted) which deals with a similar problem, but covers only the case where the parameter list is completely empty (i.e. `S s()`). I am particularly interested in the case `S(1, 2)`.

The [standard](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.fct.default#4.sentence-4) says:

> In a given function declaration, each parameter subsequent to a
>   parameter with a default argument shall have a default argument
>   supplied in this or a previous declaration or shall be a function
>   parameter pack.

So I thought that my constructor for `S` was valid and the values for `n` and `args` could be deduced in all three cases. Which compiler (if any) is correct?

Comment: Compiles fine in MSVC 15.6.2. Could be that Clang reads the instantiated function as `S(int n = 0, int deduced) {}` and somehow fails to see it as a parameter pack, thinking it is invalid since the following argument has no default.

Comment: @Barry I think the other question deals with an empty parameter list, but I am particularly interested in the `S(1, 2)` case.

Comment: @phimuemue The other question deals with the concept of having a trailing function parameter pack after a defaulted argument... the actually call is immaterial. Your code is completely correct and the linked question has clang bug reports.

Comment: @Barry Thank you for the reply. You are right: The bug report (https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=23029#c3) has something similar to my example.