# variadic template arguments with default values

Tags: c++, parameters, c++14, variadic-templates

I have a templated struct that has a method that (along with other parameters) accepts those templated parameters.

```
template<class... Types>
struct Observer
{
    void subscribe(const std::string& id, Types... args)
    {
        // store id somehow
        data = std::make_tuple(args...);
    }

    std::tuple<Types...> data;
};
```

I want to make all the templated arguments optional. So that it looks like this:

```
Observer<float, int> observer;
observer.subscribe("id1", 3.14, 4);
observer.subscribe("id2", 0.707); // this doesn't work!
observer.subscribe("id3");        // this doesn't work!
```

As far as I know there is not straight forward way? But maybe someone know a workaround or a trick.

Ideally, I'd like to provide my own defaults. Maybe like this:

```
enum class SomeEnum { Val1, Val2 };    

Observer<float, SomeEnum, 0.f, SomeEnum::Val1> observer;
observer.subscribe("id1", 3.14);
```

Here is [LIVE EXAMPLE](https://godbolt.org/z/Zl2914).

Comment: What should be the value for these parameters if no argument is supplied?

Comment: As stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29098835/can-parameter-pack-function-arguments-be-defaulted) it is specifically not allowed.  I'm not sure how you want to work around it since some types are not default constructable.

Comment: @Quentin I'd like to provide my own defaults. Updated the description

Answer (score 2):

In C++17 you can simply do something like:

```
template<class... Types>
struct Observer
{
    static constexpr std::tuple<Types...> defaults{42, 24, 99};

    template<class... Args>
    void subscribe(Args... args)
    {
        if constexpr (sizeof...(Types) > sizeof...(Args)) {
            subscribe(args..., std::get<sizeof...(Args)>(defaults));
        } else {
            // whatever you need with `args...`
        }
    }
};
```

Here I am simply picking them from `Observer::defaults`, but feel free to compute them however you want.

For C++14 and below, you will need to emulate the `if constexpr`. See e.g. [Constexpr if alternative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43587405/constexpr-if-alternative) for alternatives.

Comment: this could actually work. But do you have any idea on how to provide defaults for custom types? I updated description to show usage example

Answer (score 1):

Boost.Mp11 for the win:

```cpp
template <typename... Ts>
void subscribe(const std::string& id, Ts const&... args)
{
    static_assert(sizeof...(Ts) <= sizeof...(Types));
    using Rest = mp_drop_c<std::tuple<Types...>, sizeof...(Ts)>;
    data = std::tuple_cat(std::make_tuple(args...), Rest());
}
```

The assumes that value initialization of the trailing arguments is fine. If it's not, you'll have to figure out what to do with `Us`.

---

Works nicer if you actually make the optional more explicit:

```cpp
template<class... Types>
struct Observer
{
    using Data = std::tuple<std::optional<Types>...>;

    template <typename... Ts>
    void subscribe(const std::string& id, Ts const&... args)
    {
        static_assert(sizeof...(Ts) <= sizeof...(Types));
        using Rest = mp_drop_c<Data, sizeof...(Ts)>;
        data = std::tuple_cat(std::make_tuple(args...), Rest());
    }

    Data data;
};
```

Comment: do you know if it also could work with custom defaults? I updated the description

Comment: `s/make_tuple/tie/g`